# Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MyProvider: ([object Object], [object Object], ?, [object Object])

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I've found many questions already talking about this problem, but somehow none seemed to propose a working solution in my case.

When I run my app, I get the following message:
`Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MyModel: ([object Object], [object Object], ?, [object Object]).`

The third argument passed to MyModel's constructor is a provider that I created myself (as well as the three other arguments). That provider itself uses other providers, but I've checked for looping dependencies, and there are none.
Also, no error is thrown at compilation time.

I really can't understand where that error comes from. I've checked the app's code, app.module.ts... but everything seem to be ok. Any idea?

°°*In case that's useful*°°: myModel is a provider that I created, it's located in a directory which path is `/src/models/someModel/myModel.ts` (here the root being the root of my app).
I have other providers located in `/src/providers/`. I use two distinct folders because the purpose of the providers in those folders are slightly different.

Comment: can you show both the file that references `myModel` and `myModel` also ?

Comment: Have you added `@Injectable()` decorator to all the providers that are injected?

Comment: @AmitChigadani Yes, I've added @Injectable() to all injected providers

Comment: @Hussein It's not so easy to show the whole code, because there are a really many providers and models, and many dependency depths. I've started declaring the problematic providers with `@Inject(forwardRef(() => MyModel)) public myModel: MyModel` which seemed to solve the issue, but now I get the following error with one provider that is really cyclical, and has to call another provider which itself will call indirectly the first `Error: Provider parse errors:
Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! M_dionisos ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1`

Comment: that means 2 or more services depending on each other, which they shouldn't, try to organize your services more

Comment: @Hussein Yes some services depend on each other, but it's part of the code and it's actually desired. But it seem to be working when I don't import them directly in the constructor and do like this: `setTimeout(() => this.myProvider = injector.get(MyProvider))`. It's a hack, but it actually seem necessary for my code.

Comment: i don't suggest you to do this, instead try to organize the services, maybe add another service in between